# Tomcat not uploading all files

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

When i make the war i see the XCV.Jar, but I add the project on Tomcat (IDE eclipse), and when I deploy it, I have all jars except XCV.Jar (This jar is the parent of the project I deployed).

Comment: can you clearify how 'this jar is parent of the project deployed'?

Comment: Are you jarring a project up and including it in the WEB-INF/lib folder? Is that what you mean by parent?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy to Tomcat from Eclipse it often fails to clean up the work directory directory. Try to clean $TOMCAT_HOME/work/Catalina// and the web apps directory then try redeploying.

If you are running tomcat inside eclipse you're asking for trouble. Its often better to build and validate the .war independently(with ant or maven) then deploy manually or with a script.